# Redirect .php to extensionless URL only for non-dynamic URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to 301 redirect pages with a .php extension to their extensionless version. Using the rule below, pages with a query parameter fail (signup.php?login=true) or result in a redirect loop.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]
```

I'd therefor like to exclude dynamic urls (It doesn't seem to make sense to rewrite them anyway). I've written the code below but the condition still seems to match dynamic urls.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301]
```

Can anyone help me adjust my condition to prevent dynamic urls from being rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Ensure that there are 2 spaces between `\.php\` and `[NC]

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#any url with .php and no anchor or query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^\ ]+)\.php\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301]
```